# How to solve empty parameters passed to an XQuery function in eXist-db

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am passing a parameter (`'articles-counter'`) from a form to a function in an eXist-db app.

If there is nothing passed (the field is not filled in), this works:

```
let $xmldb-food := 
    (
        let $articles-counter := 
            (
                let $counter-passed := request:get-parameter('articles-counter', '')
                return
                    if ($counter-passed) then
                        $counter-passed
                    else ()
            )
        for $uri at $count in (1 to xs:integer($articles-counter))
        let $param := request:get-parameter(concat('article-uri-', $count), '')
        return
            if ($param ne '') then
                string-join($param, ',')
            else ()
    )
```

The next example does not. It throws `xs:integer` is expected (in the `for` range) but got `''`. What is going on here? I would think it is almost the same:

```
let $xmldb-food := 
    (
        let $articles-counter := request:get-parameter('articles-counter', '')
        for $uri at $count in (1 to xs:integer($articles-counter))
        let $param := request:get-parameter(concat('article-uri-', $count), '')
        return
            if ($param ne '') then
                string-join($param, ',')
            else ()
    )
```

What is the difference between `''` and `()` (empty sequence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking the `xs:integer()` constructor with an empty string will throw a (dynamic runtime) error. Invoking with an empty sequence returns an empty sequence.

You could filter out the empty string (and any other invalid integer values) with a predicate to avoid the dynamic error condition:

```
for $uri at $count in (1 to xs:integer($articles-counter[. castable as xs:integer]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, elegant and pro solution. At first I treated that with the simplest if-then-else loop and it worked but this is better!